# Force two rows to combine/sum without concatenation in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the below results from my query. The problem is that I cannot seem to make the two rows with `90` as the AutoDel to combine/sum together. The AutoDel and DaysActive columns should just combine (meaning stay at `90` and `89` respectively) while the remaining columns sum together. I realize this behavior is due to how the `GROUP BY` clause does not see the `el.RemoveAfter` and `s.AutoDeleteDays` columns having the same values; the day figure is either pulled from one or from the other. How can I "force" those two rows together?

Results:

```
AutoDel DaysActive  ActiveVids  TotalHrs    TotalMiB    TotalGiB    % of Total
90      89          7420        1128        1017101     993.26      18.74  -- 'NULL' row
-1      322         3516        1021        912037      890.66      16.81
90      89          10718       1578        1422796     1389.45     26.22  -- '0' row
30      28          268         1           1687        1.65        0.03
365     339         6576        1402        1257035     1227.57     23.17
1825    335         1762        421         377548      368.70      6.96
2190    316         558         138         123749      120.85      2.28
```

Desired Results:

```
AutoDel DaysActive  ActiveVids  TotalHrs    TotalMiB    TotalGiB    % of Total
-1      322         3516        1021        912037      890.66      16.81
30      28          268         1           1687        1.65        0.03
90      89          18138       2706        2439897     2382.71     44.96
365     339         6576        1402        1257035     1227.57     23.17
1825    335         1762        421         377548      368.70      6.96
2190    316         558         138         123749      120.85      2.28
```

Event table (`SELECT DISTINCT RemoveAfter`):

```
NULL
-1
0
30
365
1825
2190
```

The `90` found in the results gets pulled from the "global" setting found in my system settings table. Both `NULL` and `0` get evaluated to be `90` on the application side and should for my results as well.

Query:

```
DECLARE @total AS DEC = (
    SELECT
        SUM(ef.FileLength) / 1048576
    FROM Core.dbo.Event AS e
        JOIN Core.dbo.EventFile AS ef
            ON e.Id = ef.EventId
    WHERE e.Deleted = 0
)

SELECT
    COALESCE(NULLIF(el.RemoveAfter, 0), s.AutoDeleteDays) AS AutoDel,
    DATEDIFF(d, MIN(e.CreatedOn), MAX(e.CreatedOn)) AS DaysActive,
    COUNT(e.Id) AS ActiveVids,
    SUM(e.duration) / 3600000 AS TotalHrs,
    SUM(ef.FileLength) / 1048576 AS TotalMiB,
    CAST(SUM(CAST(ef.filelength AS decimal)) / 1073741824 AS decimal(18,2)) AS TotalGiB,
    FORMAT((SUM(ef.FileLength) / 1048576) / @total * 100, 'N2') AS '% of Total'
FROM Core.dbo.EventIdList AS el
    LEFT JOIN Core.dbo.Event AS e
        ON el.id = e.EventId
    LEFT JOIN Core.dbo.EventFile AS ef
        ON ef.EventId = el.Id
    CROSS JOIN Core.dbo.SystemSetting AS S
WHERE e.Deleted = 0 
    OR e.Deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY e.RemoveAfter, s.AutoDeleteDays
```

And yes, I know that formatting should be handled application side, but this query is for me to quickly grab info from the DB through SSMS; I wanted the information to be easily readable.

Comment: I don't understand what is the result that you want, can you post the desired result?

Comment: @Lamak - Just added the desired results in above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler way would be to use your current result as a CTE or a derived table:

```
DECLARE @total AS DEC = (
    SELECT
        SUM(ef.FileLength) / 1048576
    FROM Core.dbo.Event AS e
        JOIN Core.dbo.EventFile AS ef
            ON e.Id = ef.EventId
    WHERE e.Deleted = 0
);

WITH CTE AS
(  
    SELECT
        COALESCE(NULLIF(el.RemoveAfter, 0), s.AutoDeleteDays) AS AutoDel,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(e.CreatedOn), MAX(e.CreatedOn)) AS DaysActive,
        COUNT(e.Id) AS ActiveVids,
        SUM(e.duration) / 3600000 AS TotalHrs,
        SUM(ef.FileLength) / 1048576 AS TotalMiB,
        CAST(SUM(CAST(ef.filelength AS decimal)) / 1073741824 AS decimal(18,2)) AS TotalGiB,
        FORMAT((SUM(ef.FileLength) / 1048576) / @total * 100, 'N2') AS '% of Total'
    FROM Core.dbo.EventIdList AS el
        LEFT JOIN Core.dbo.Event AS e
            ON el.id = e.EventId
        LEFT JOIN Core.dbo.EventFile AS ef
            ON ef.EventId = el.Id
        CROSS JOIN Core.dbo.SystemSetting AS S
    WHERE e.Deleted = 0 
        OR e.Deleted IS NULL
    GROUP BY e.RemoveAfter, 
             s.AutoDeleteDays
)
SELECT  AutoDel,
        DaysActive,
        SUM(ActiveVids) ActiveVids,
        SUM(TotalHrs) TotalHrs,
        SUM(TotalMiB) TotalMiB,
        SUM(TotalGiB) TotalGiB,
        SUM([% of Total]) [% of Total]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY AutoDel,
         DaysActive
;
```

Comment: Gives me `Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @Trevor sorry, didn't read the question correctly. I updated my answer

Comment: That works great! I had to pull the `FORMAT` out of the CTE and use it in the bottom-most select statement instead, but it did the trick! Funny thing is, I thought that maybe I could use a CTE to get what I wanted, but quickly dismissed the idea a few days ago and never came back to it! Thanks Lamak!